# How to configure dataType parameter of @EventHubTrigger?

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to configure dataType parameter of EventHubTrigger. I will be configuring dataType parameter as binary in function app configuration.

Mycode:

```
@FunctionName("EventHubProcessor")
    public void run(
            @EventHubTrigger(name = "message", eventHubName = "%EventhubName%", connection = "AzureWebJobsEventHubSender", consumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroup_Name%",dataType = "%dataType%", cardinality = Cardinality.MANY) List<String> messages,
            final ExecutionContext context
    )
```

I'm trying in the above way. Is it the right way of configuring dataType?
Can anyone suggest on the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the code by passing **datatype** parameter of EventHubTrigger as `dataType = "%dataType%"`.

1. Defined dataType="string" in local.settings.json:
   [image]
2. I tried passing parameter as `dataType = "%dataType%"`in EventHubTrigger.java, got the below error.
   [image]
3. when we run the code, the value is getting stored as dataType="%dataType%" in **function.json:** instead of the type of data(i.e., string) which we are passing in local.settings.json as shown below.
   [image]

- **Try below code:**

4. Instead, I tried to pass **dataType="string"** as parameter in eventtrigger.java and got the expected result.

   **EventHubTrigger.java:**

   ```
   @FunctionName("EventHubTriggerJava1")

   public  void  run(

   @EventHubTrigger(name = "message", eventHubName = "kpeventhub", connection = "EventHubNSkp_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB", consumerGroup = "$Default", cardinality = Cardinality.MANY,dataType = "string") List<String> message,

   final  ExecutionContext  context

   ) {

   context.getLogger().info("Java Event Hub trigger function executed.");

   context.getLogger().info("Length:" + message.size());

   message.forEach(singleMessage  -> context.getLogger().info(singleMessage));

   }

   }
   ```
5. Executing the function locally by providing request body:
   [image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]